# Tell from Which table MySQL COALESCE returned the value

Tags: mysql, sql

i have the following part of query:

```
SUM(COALESCE(user_a, user_b)) AS income_adsense
```

Now, i have a html table in my web app where i present the data from this query.
problem is i want to mark data in one color if answer is from col `user_a` and different color if answer is from `user_b` col.

is there a way to achieve that in my query itself? (some sort of flag maybe?) 
. 
right now the only solution i have is to return all col's and work with the data on the client side but i am wondering if there's a cleaner/best practice solution.

guess it's worth mentioning i don't want to change the table structure.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: You are using `sum()`.  On different rows, the value could come from different columns.

Comment: And what color will you use if, say 50% results in your `sum` came from `user_a` but another 50% came from `user_b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to make sense of the data I would do something like:

```
CASE 
    WHEN SUM(user_a) > SUM(user_b) 
        THEN 'User_A' 
    ELSE 'User_B' 
END [Most of the data comes from]
```

You could also have two separate `SUM()` columns to make sense of this and compare the sum of values in your application.

```
SUM(user_a)    [User_A Score Weight]
, SUM(user_b)  [User_B Score Weight]
```